# Show value of clicked cell and another value from the same row in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am using following macro to show value of clicked cell (range A5:A200) in A1 cell:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A5:A200")) Is Nothing Then
            Range("A1").Value = Selection.Value
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

...and it works great. Additionally in A2 I'd like to show related value from C column.

Example:
I click on A10 -> and see the value in A1, then in A2 i'd like to see the value from C10 cell

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize the `.row` property of `Selection`. But, you already have `Target` being used from the arugument within the `Worksheet_Selection()` event as your "Selection" range, and using that range is preferred over using selection.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A5:A200")) Is Nothing Then
            Range("A1").Value = Target.Value
            Range("A2").Value = Cells(Target.row, "C")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

So replace your selection ranges with `Target`, and use the `row` property within `Cell()` to get your value from the C column.

Comment: Worked great! Thank you!